# Printing a TDBGrid

Tags: delphi, printing, tdbgrid

I'm working with Delphi 2009 and I really need to create a button that can print all my data in a DBGrid. I appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is a DB grid then you can create a report using any of the report components you have, or you can do without them by using the printers unit, by iterating over the data and print them using a printer.textout

Answer (score 1):

Get TxcellentFormPrinter control below and then you can print the Entire Grid.

http://www.code4sale.com/joehecht/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the TSMPrintData component from SMReport Autogenerated suite:
http://www.scalabium.com/smr

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want but if you want to set your data into a TDbGrid then set your data into a dataset and link your dataset with the TDbGrid.
But if you want to print your data from a DbGrid see [Print a TDBGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496813/print-a-tdbgrid/7498676#7498676)